# Building a '$resource' service for multiple API calls

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-resource, angularjs-http

I have created a factory service that can get data from an API with the following code.

```
app.factory('Book', ['$resource','$http', function($resource, $http) {
    return $resource('http://someurl.com/api/book/', {}, {
      query: {method:'GET', isArray:false}
    });
  }]);
```

The above code works for fetching the data but I would like to have a single service that I can parse and then have access to all the different api calls. Below is the theoretical way to build it with ***$http*** service, but I cannot get this to work. And I would also like to have the functionality of ***$resource***. What I was hoping for was for someone to give me pointers with syntax how I can seperate each ***$resource*** "call" into a function attached to the service? Like done with the ***$http*** service below.

```
app.service('dataService', ['$resource','$http', function($resource, $http) {    
    var urlBase = 'http://someurl.com/api/';

    this.getBooks = function () {
        return $http.get(urlBase + 'book')
    };

    this.getArticles = function () {
        return $http.get(urlBase + 'articles');
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Can't you instead of the `$http.get(urlBase + 'book')` put `$resource(urlBase + 'book').get();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edited to reflect your needs. Haven't tried running it though.

```
app.factory('DataService', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource('http://someurl.com/api/:path', {
            path: '@path'
        }, {
            getBook: {
                method: 'GET',
                params: {
                    path: 'book'
                }
            }
        }, {
            getArticles: {
                method: 'GET',
                params: {
                    path: 'articles'
                },
                isArray: true
            }
        });
    }
])
```

Then in your controller, just call the resource service with the right path :

```
this.getBook = function() {
    $scope.book = DataService.getBook({}, function success() {
        //your code
    }, function err() {
        //your code
    });
};

this.getArticles = function() {
    $scope.articles = DataService.getArticles({}, function success() {
        //your code
    }, function err() {
        //your code
    });
};
```

Comment: Almost, I was hoping to have the logic the other way around - so that my paths are defined in the service allowing me to call `DataService.getBooks();` or `DataService.getArticles();` in the controller.

Comment: How can we pass different number of params to the same resource url, is that possible at all?

Answer (score 2):

The solution above by [Goodzilla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1523011/goodzilla) worked - but I ended up using the solution by [Gustav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2760557/gustav)

```
app.service('dataService', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    var urlBase = 'http://someurl.com/api/';

    this.getBooks = function () {
        return $resource(urlBase + 'Books').get();
    };

    this.getArticles = function () {
        return $resource(urlBase + 'Articles').get();
    };

}]);
```

And the controller

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'dataService', function($scope, DataService) {
    $scope.logBook = DataService.getBooks();
}]);
```